# Dynamic Placement in Blender?

Tags: add-on, physics, transforms

I saw this feature of Cinema4D here:
[Feature](https://youtu.be/3y13ZfpWzeg)

Can i do that in Blender and move objects that attract with each other without using physics modifier and apply it and that hard work,
Is there a feature like that or Addon?

Comment: [How to link directly to a specific point in time of a YouTube video](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/732/linking-directly-to-a-specific-point-in-time-of-a-youtube-video).

Comment: No ... from what I know.

Comment: Same...AFAIK no.